# VBA IE put value to webage form

Tags: html, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTy41.jpg)I am really new to VBA-HTML.  I can get ID from html and put value on it but i failed on this one(error message 91).

Could you please help?

```
<INPUT name=form:custId tabIndex=1 title=統一編號 class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all inputCheck placeholdersjs placeholdersjs placeholdersjs" id=form:custId role=textbox aria-disabled=false aria-readonly=false onfocus=checkCapsLock() onblur="$('.warning_box').hide();" type=text value=統一編號 jQuery1113006539849326140401="12" autocomplete="off" placeholder="統一編號" data-placeholder-bound="true" data-placeholder-value="統一編號" data-placeholder-active="true" data-placeholder-maxlength="10">
```

My code:

```
Sub firstb ()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application") 
ie.Visible = True  
ie.Navigate("https://ebank.firstbank.com.tw/PTLB2C/index.xhtml")

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.ReadyState <> 4 DoEvents Loop

ie.Document.forms(0).all("form:custId").Value = "lmiltamy" ''(error message 91).

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  I've edited your post so that the code is formatted and visible.  Please re-edit your post so that the code has proper line breaks, indentation, etc.  Don't add code in comments, as it is impossible to read, and later people who visit your question may miss the added detail, thanks!

Comment: hi robsiemb, thanks for your help. i am a new member of Stackoverflow. still figure out how to edit and post.

Comment: No problem -- just make sure you don't remove the markup when you edit (the backticks), especially for the HTML, as it will render the content invisible.  You can see the [markup help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as well.

Comment: Is that really what the html for the input looks like? Can you copy paste the html from the page for that element and use the snippet tool via  [edit] to insert. Also, does the error still occur if you execute the code slowly line by line with F8?

Comment: i added a photo of html and provide the link of webpage, thanks for the help^^

Comment: Could someone take a look? Thanks

Comment: I have been trying all the methods as below, still can not input value

Set A = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
Set b = ie.Document.getElementsByName("form:custId")(0)
 no value for a and b 
Set c = ie.Document.getElementByclassname("ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all inputCheck ui-state-focus")(0)
c--error 438